# Is the America the Beautiful Annual Pass a car decal?

Tags: usa, fees-and-charges, national-parks

I was considering buying the pass, but I want to know if it is something that is permanently attached to a car or something that can be carried on my person. I think it may be a wallet card, but I can't tell.

Let's assume I'm buying it online.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is a physical card, around the same size as a credit card.

On the back is a space for 2 signatures. The person using the card must be one of the two people that has signed the card, and you need to show additional ID (eg, a drivers license) to prove that.

When you purchase it they will punch a hole in the card to set the expiry month, with the expiry year printed on the card itself.

Comment: While not 100% sure, I believe the new cards are plastic and not punched as they used to be (I know my new old farts pass is).

Comment: @Tom: I got a new AtB annual pass a couple weeks ago.  It is plastic, just like a credit card, and it is punched.

Comment: The 2017 (expiry) cards are definitely plastic, and 'punched'. I'm fairly sure the 2018 ones are the same. They also bend out of shape a little if you leave them on a hot car dash...

Answer (score 2):

If you are 62 or older AND are an American Citizen or permanent resident, you should get an America the Beautiful SENIOR pass.  It is $10.00 and is lifetime.

Read details at https://www.nps.gov/planyourvisit/passes.htm